# How to populate data to modal of bootstrap when a button is clicked?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I want to populate each of this array values whenever a button is clicked:

```
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
                                        $prodId = $row["ProductID"];
                                        $imgID = $row["ImageID"];
                                        $prodName = $row["ProductName"];
                                        $prodPrice = $row["ProductPrice"];
                                        $prodDesc = $row["prodDesc"];
                                        $imgURL = $row["ImageUrl"];
                                        $proNum = $prodId;
                                        $dynamicListCol1 = '<div class="thumbnail" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <img src="' . $imgURL . '" width="200" height="300" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
    <center>
    <div class="caption">
    <h4>' . $prodName . '</h4>
    <p>Price: $' . $prodPrice . ' <br>Description: ' . $prodDesc . ' <br></p>
     <a data-toggle="modal" href="#cartModal">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnCart">
       <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> Cart it</button>
     </a>
     <a data-toggle="modal" href="#prodModal"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
     <i class="icon-search"></i> View it</button>
     </a>
    </div>
   </center>
</div>';
echo $dynamicListCol1;
```

I want to fetch each values of `$prodName` and `$prodPrice` when the `btnCart` is clicked.
and populate it inside a table in a modal.

```
Product    Price
Ebook      $200
Ebook2     $150
```

so on and so forth...

Answer (score 0):

You have to write JS code which will send an AJAX request each time when a button will be clicked. In this AJAX request you will populate your data and send back to browser prepared HTML, like you generate in your question. After a response will be received, your JS code has to show TB modal popup with HTML received in AJAX response.